# CommunityToolkit.Mvvm: Change source generated property setter behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, sourcegenerators, mvvm-toolkit

As topic says. Is it possible to "inject" some null check in source generated setter method?
I am using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` **8.1.0.0**

For this demo I have simple class `Test` with private field `_someProperty` with `[ObservableProperty]` on top of it.

**Source generated setter and getter**

```cs
public object SomeProperty
{
    get => _someProperty;
    set
    {
        if (!global::System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals(_someProperty, value))
        {
            OnSomePropertyChanging(value);
            OnPropertyChanging(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangingArgs.SomeProperty);
            _someProperty = value;
            OnSomePropertyChanged(value);
            OnPropertyChanged(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangedArgs.SomeProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

**My goal: Same, but with null check injected**

```cs
public object SomeProperty
{
    get => _someProperty;
    set
    {
        if (value is null)
            return;
        if (!global::System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals(_someProperty, value))
        {
            OnSomePropertyChanging(value);
            OnPropertyChanging(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangingArgs.SomeProperty);
            _someProperty = value;
            OnSomePropertyChanged(value);
            OnPropertyChanged(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangedArgs.SomeProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to check if value is null and omit setting it in setter.
In my project I have two DataGrids and TreeView that handles `SelectedItem` event. They are binding to the same `SelectedOobject`. This object is initialized in constructor and I don't really want it to be null. This may happen if I refresh DataGrid (cause of filtering) and `SelectedOobject` may not be "available" in current view and it automatically set to `null`. I'd rather still use an old object (old reference) than `null` which becoming annoying to check it in every method.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't seem like an appropriate scenario for Source Generators, it's also not supported in that way, AFAIK. If you want to prevent that `null` is assigned to your reference, you should enable [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Answer (score 0):

My "workaround" for this case is to create another `_tmpSomeProperty` with `[ObservableProperty]` attribute. Bind this property to `SelectedItem` DataGrid.
Then create partial method:

```cs
partial void OnTmpSomePropertyChanged(object value)
{
    if (value is null)
        return;
    // do other checks if needed
    SomeProperty = value;
}
```

With this approach I can control `SomeProperty`. Is it kinda redundant? I think... But it works as I want.